# Run testng.xml from the terminal on a mac

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, testng

I cannot seem to figure out how to execute testng.xml on my mac.

I went though these steps numerous times but still says "Error: Could not find or load main class org.testng.TestNG"

I am able to execute testng.xml from eclipse but cannot do it from terminal. Has anybody used the commands below successfully?

```
set classpath = %ProjectPath%\bin;%ProjectPath%\Lib\*

java org.testng.TestNG %ProjectPath%\TestXml.xml
```

---

My bash profile is

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile" # Load the default .profile

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*

export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export JRE_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)

# Apache Ant
export ANT_HOME=Users/Skyfeedback/QATesting/ant

#export to PATH 
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/Skyfeedback/QATesting/ant/bin
```

Comment: Paths with % and `;`, and files with `\​` are a windows-only syntax. On Mac and Linux, you use environment variables with `$` before them, and separate path elements with `:`.

Comment: can you please give me an example of environment variiable set for ?  Environment variable for testng.xml? Yes i changed slashes .

Comment: my current bash profile looks like this [[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile" # Load the default .profile

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*

export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export JRE_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)

# Apache Ant
export ANT_HOME=Users/Skyfeedback/QATesting/ant

#export to PATH 
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/Skyfeedback/QATesting/ant/bin

Comment: Don't put stuff like that into comments. It's unreadable. Edit your question and add the information, properly formatted, to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Steps to execute **testng.xml** in mac terminal

1. Download: **testng.jar** and **jcommander.jar** put them in the same folder (for convenience). e.g: ***jarFiles*** folder in project folder
2. compile .java file: javac -cp "../jarFiles/*" *.java (assume you are in the class folder)
3. run: java -cp  **".:../jarFiles/*" org.testng.TestNG ../testng.xml**

Note that: **.:** in step 3 means that the .class file is in current directory.

refer to this [link](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/testng-beginners-guide/9781782166009/ch02s05.html)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Your commands are not unix/mac specific. The slash you use is the wrong way.

Windows \

Unix and Mac /

### Change your \ to /

Answer (score 0):

## Working code snippet for Mac

java -cp "Full_path_to_your_project_bin_directory:Full_path_to_your_project jar_directory" org.testng.TestNG path_to_your_xml_file_dir/fileName.xml

**Note :** Keep all the jar files under same directory.

**Example:**
java -cp "/Users/fidanza/LearnTestNG/bin:/Users/fidanza/SeleniumStuffs/Jars/*" org.testng.TestNG ~/LearnTestNG/testRun.xml

Answer (score 0):

I have TestNG installed in eclipse so, just expanded TestNG library in Package Explorer, copied the path of testng jar file and added in my command,
my Project name is *DemoJenkinsProject* (reach in project folder through cd command, then execute the command), remember to change the testng jar name according to the jar file you have in your Eclipse/plugins folder.

**[Ashutoshs-Air:DemoJenkinsProject ashutoshanand$ java -cp "/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins/org.testng_6.14.3.r201802240500.jar:/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins/com.beust.jcommander_1.72.0.jar:bin" org.testng.TestNG testng.xml**

Welcome to Jenkins

---

### Suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0

[Terminal Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0o9AJ.png)